# a Reference to 'Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library' could not be added

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, com

I'm unable to add reference to 'Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library' with VS2012. Any ideas, what could cause this issue?

When I try to create reference to the COM component, I get this error message "a reference to 'Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library' could not be added".

The VS project is basic class library (c# x86).

Comment: Which is the framework? is it in 4.5? try it in 4.0? I tried to add the same to class Library in .Net 4.0 VS 2010

Comment: The Framework is .NET 4.0 Client Profile. I also tried to add it to .NET 4.0 Full with the same results.

Comment: Use .Net 4.0 Full Profile, but I tried with the both the Profile, It work fine, Any way you are using .Net 4.0, Do u have VS 2010, can u just  try , let me know whether its solves the Issue,because am using .Net 4.0 VS 2010, I didn't get any Issue.?

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. I just get another error message "Library not registered". I think I need to find another way to check the MSI version, because I can not trust that MSI.dll is registered correctly in target environment.

Answer (score 27):

In Visual Studio go to References > Add Reference... > COM > Browse... > `%WINDIR%\system32\msi.dll`.

Worked for me on VS2012.

Comment: Work on VS2013 also. I posted a sample here: https://github.com/JohanPGunnarsson/GetParameterInfoFromMSI, which reads parameters from MSIs, like "ProductVersion". It references msi.dll from System32.

Comment: Does not work on 2017 for me at all. Same damn error.

Answer (score -3):

Check ur Regedit , Please check these Values

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{000C1092-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.0
```

**If Visual Studio 2010 Installed**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ComponentPickerPages\Recent\{9A341D96-5A64-11D3-BFF9-00C04F990235}\1
```

**If Visual Studio 2008 Installed**

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ComponentPickerPages\Recent\{9A341D96-5A64-11D3-BFF9-00C04F990235}\1
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help anyone?