# open a website address in excel tabs using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet , in Column A, there are some addresses in cells i want to open these cell url address in different tabs ( excel worksheets within a workbook), 
Can anyone please help 
In vba excel , i have met this type of problem first time, I can make it to open with google chrome , or IE etc
But client needs to open it within excel workbook in sheets

Later part is to save these files as pdf files in computer , that is not a problem for me , i can do it well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I embed a browser in an Excel VBA form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501213/how-do-i-embed-a-browser-in-an-excel-vba-form)

Comment: Different applications exist for different needs. Excel is not a browser. To open a website inside excel would just be using an embedded control which are generally very poor.

Comment: @JimmyShoe yes it is poor , when it is required specifically , no option is left then

Comment: I can open in google chrome or IE, but was not able to find any clue to open web address within excel , but now i have , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This : (Dont forget to add http or https)

```
Sub OpenURL()
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
    ' Or ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
    ' Or ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www." & ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) & ".com"  (B1 has stackoverflow word).
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your comment
there is not only one link that i want to open
A1,A2,A3 etc are having url address, not hyperlink, i want a code which will read link from A1, open in new worksheet not workbook , then same for other cells

Comment: @Adiba Qudoos, I' ve added more samples for you ... Maybe you can add sample values for to be clear ...